# how to implement neural artwork to get art painting images for ios?

Tags: ios, neural-network, imagefilter

so, the question is that i want to implement filters like prisma app, i found that neural art work deep learning can be used to do it. But how to implement it in objective c or swift ? Anyone have any idea say ? thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Convolutional Neural Network for that. As a framework i suggest using TensorFlow. It works perfectly with CNN's plus the code can be written in C++.

Here is the sample https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples/